# Logstash does not read csv files from the folder (*.csv)

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm using logstash to push log data from csv files into elastic search. This is my configuration file to push the csv files into elasticsearch.

```
 input 
  {  
    file {
     path => "C:\Projects\Tools\ELK\data\CI_Report\*.csv"
     start_position =>"beginning"
  }
 }

filter {
 csv {
  columns =>["LOG_LEVEL", "TOOL_ID", "ID_ANALYSIS", "ARCH_COMP", "Files",   
          "Component Analysed","Date","Tool Version"]
 separator =>","
 }
 }
output {
   elasticsearch { 
   hosts => ["localhost"]
   index => "cilog_all"
}
 stdout {
  codec => json
 }
}
```

This is my command to start the logstash, logstash -f logcsv.conf

Note : It works If I use the actual file path to a single csv file. It never works if I use *.csv to load log data from all csv files located in the specified folder.

Is Glob pattern supported by logstash input plugin ? as mentioned here 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/glob-support.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks ok save for your path.
Being windows you need to change the path to this as \ is an escape character

```
path => "C:/Projects/Tools/ELK/data/CI_Report/*.csv"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! . It works now. but \ is working fine if path is pointing to single file like this "C:\Projects\Tools\ELK\data\CI_Report\test.csv"..

Comment: You're correct, it's when the wildcard is brought in that the \ becomes an escape character.